# How can i make multiple http requests in a factory

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering if we can load multiple json files using a factory and a controller.

Im pulling classifieds.json and myWords.json.

Im seeing content from the former, but the content from the latter is not being displayed

This is how i tired to incorporate it. I've checked the propriety of myWords.json against a json formatter, so i know for sure that its all right.

I guess, im doin sthg wrong here. Id appreciate if you could guide me in the right direction.

[Factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RIKv.png)

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqpG6.png)

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570618/multiple-http-with-promise-using-factory-angular

Answer (score 1):

In order to fetch data from multiple sources, the currect way is to use one method for each data source.

### Factory:

```
function getClassified() {
  return $http.get('data/classified.json');
}
function getMyWords() {
  return $http.get('data/myWords.json');
}

return {
  getClassified : getClassified,
  getMyWords : getMyWords
}
```

### Controller

```
classifiedsFactory.getClassified().then(function(data) {
  $scope.classified = data;
};
classifiedsFactory.getMyWords().then(function(data) {
  $scope.myWords = data;
}
```

If you have more than 2 source that you want to get together, you can use $q service in your factory:

```
function getAllData() {
  var source1 = $http.get('source1.json');
  var source2 = $http.get('source2.json');
  ...
  ...
  return $q.all([source1, source2, ...]);
}
```

This will resolve only when all data have been recieved and you can get it in your controller.

Don't forget to include $q in your factory function dependencies

Comment: thanks for the direction Kobi; ive been following the instructions to no avail. https://github.com/sfumatostar/ngclassifieds/blob/End_of_Section_7/components/classifieds/classifieds.ctr.js

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pGEOENtZL9HQ4F3qbDDI?p=info)

```
Hi Ashim09,
```

Here I added sample for multiple json call in factory..